# Issues with Starting Pentaho Community Edition server

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to install Pentaho Community Edition 7.0 BA server on CentOS 6.8 and getting the following error.

HTTP Status 404 - /pentaho

type Status report

message /pentaho

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.37

The file I downloaded and unzipped was pentaho-server-ce-7.0.0.0-25.zip

I've checked the ports (8080, and 9092) and they are open and listening. 
I tried to change tcp port to 9093, but still does not work.

I thoguht it worked out of the box but I'm having trouble.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me when installing on Ubuntu 16.04.

It turned out to be the Java version being used. Since I am running several versions of PDI alongside each other, I have both Java 7 and 8 installed and it was picking the 7.

The proper solution is to configure the PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the java 8 installation, for example "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle". I couldn't do that without breaking some older applications.

What I ended up doing is hacking start-pentaho.sh, commenting out the lines involving setPentahoEnv and instead putting the hardcoded values:

`_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
_PENTAHO_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java`

Fill in your own Java paths obviously and don't forget the starting underscores.